# What is the difference between who > lp and who | lp?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pipe

Why does the `who > lp` creates a file but `who | lp` leads the output to program `lp`?

What is the underlying principle behind these two simple commands?
Can somebody explain it with an example?

Comment: A common mistake here is to think that `lp file.txt` and (for example) `cat file.txt | lp` are the same (that is, that the pipe somehow assemblies the file, row by row, and makes an argument of that data, and passes it to lp) - this is a common mistake, because the result (in this case, what is printed) may be identical. But those interfaces (argument(s), and a pipe to `STDIN`) are not at all the same. As an illustration, try it with echo, and not lp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>` is redirection to a file. `|` is a redirection to a process through the use of a pipe.

The latter essentially points file descriptor 1 (`STDOUT`) of one process to a pipe which leads to file descriptor 0 (`STDIN`) of another process. A file redirection operation is not as complex, it merely takes an FD and dumps it to a file.